# Setting MONGO_URL not applying remote mongo connection to Atlas from local run

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to connect to a remote mongodb setup on MongoDB Atlas from a local run. 
I have a normal mongo url from Compose:

```
 MONGO_URL=mongodb://[username]:[password]@aws-us-east-1-portal.21.dblayer.com:10170/[database]
```

This works fine for remote connection on local runs and for deployment to Galaxy.

I have made a more complex replica set setup with Atlas and would like to connect to that database set from local development and in production. 
The Atlas url looks like this:

```
 MONGO_URL=mongodb://[username]:[password]@cluster0-shard-00-00-xgnuk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xgnuk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xgnuk.mongodb.net:27017/[database]?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&readPreference=primaryPreferred&w=majority&authSource=admin
```

When I deploy to Galaxy, my app connects successfully to the desired Atlas database. However, when I try to set the url locally to the remote database, like I use to with the compose url, my local app instance only connects to my local mongodb with no warnings or errors.

I tried playing around with the option settings in the url, but with no success. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

(No sharding is enabled)

Comment: Seems strange. When you change the Atlas URL to the Compose URL, does it work as intended?

Comment: Yes. Always. So the Compose URL works on local dev and in Galaxy deployment, and the Atlas URL works in Galaxy deployment but not on local dev. It only starts up the local mongodb in local dev instead of connecting to Atlas.

Comment: I guess, this issues is resolved here : https://forums.meteor.com/t/setting-mongo-url-not-applying-remote-mongo-connection-to-atlas-from-local-run/29718/6

Comment: @Ankit, I think that you should add that as an answer (with an explanation, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using '&' chars in a environment variable can be problematic (Mac OS). Be sure to type the variable in quotes:

```
MONGO_URL='mongodb://[username]:[password]@cluster0-shard-00-00-xgnuk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xgnuk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xgnuk.mongodb.net:27017/[database]?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&readPreference=primaryPreferred&w=majority&authSource=admin'
```

More details here:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/setting-mongo-url-not-applying-remote-mongo-connection-to-atlas-from-local-run/29718/5

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/